# Minar cryptocurrencies without software or special hardware

Tags: mining-pools, mining-theory, mining-hardware, mining-profitability, miner-configuration

I know that it is very difficult to mine at the moment without special equipment, but I think in a way, even if it is a hobby, to try to mine either by developing a program in Java or with Excel.

I have basic equipment, currently I work with Minergate.

I want to make my own mining system, as I would do the following:

1. Connect to the cryptocurrency network.
2. Read the hash
3. Interpret the hash
4. Enter the new hash

And which currency would be feasible to undermine.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking which altcoin to mine?

You mainly just need to look at www.cryptocompare.com and find some of the low priced coins.

However, Bytecoin would be a good thing to start with.